# Read json token (byte[]) as stream

Tags: java, json, jackson

Lets say that I have some json response like:

```
{
   byteProp: [1, 3, 2, ... some very large byte content]
}
```

I would like to fetch `byteProp` as stream. I have started with [JacksonStreamingApi](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi) and assumed that I should create parser like:

```
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();   
JsonParser jParser = jfactory.createJsonParser( myJsonStream);
```

Bu problem is that I don't see oppurtunity to get my `byteProp`as stream, only way to get this property is to use sth like (assume that we are on the right token)

```
jParser.getBinaryValue()
```

Which still will fetch all `byteProp` content into memory and this is the situation I would like to avoid.

Is there any way to read single json property as stream ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, improve as you see fit:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jParser = jfactory.createJsonParser(new FileInputStream(new File("data/json.json")));

if (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    return;
}
while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    String fieldName = jParser.getCurrentName();

    jParser.nextToken();
    if (fieldName.equals("byteProp")) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            if (read >= bytes.length) {
                os.write(bytes, 0, read);
                os.flush();
                bytes = new byte[1024];
                read = 0;
            }

            bytes[read++] = jParser.getByteValue();
        }
        if (read >= 0) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
            os.flush();
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(new String(os.toByteArray()));
```

Replace the `ByteArrayOutputStream` with something like a `FileOutputStream`, depending on your needs.